# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

While Importing Maven Project in eclipse, I come across the error above. I am new to these technologies, so does not make much sense.

Kindly have a look at POM.XML.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${scriptSourceDirectory}/run-webpack-dev-server.groovy</source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Full error shown as:
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.1.1:execute (execution: webpack, phase: process-resources)
Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the repair button and choose to ignore this goal.

Comment: Eclipse maven support (m2e) does not understand this custom execution, so it is warning you that it will not run the groovy script when you are building/running/testing your maven project from the IDE.  It is safe to choose "ignore" only if you do not need the outcome of the defined execution.